# Getting Type Mismatch Error while calling sub procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I am taking two input from USERFORM "CheckIn Time (`hh:mm` format)" and "Checkout Time (`hh:mm` format)" through TextBox, and trying to get immediate output in 3rd Text Box (`hh:mm` format) which shows difference between check in and checkout.

To achieve this I am using `Call Sub procedure` method.

However I am getting error

> "Run time 13: Type mismatch".

I am new to VBA and I am literally stuck at this since 2 weeks. Please help.

I tried changing DATA type but didn't get any positive result.

```
Private Sub CHKIN_Change() 'Calling GetTime 
    Call GetTime
End Sub


Private Sub CHKOUT_Change() 'Calling GetTime 
   Call GetTime
End Sub


Private Sub TOTALHRS_Change() 'Calling GetTime 
   Call GetTime
End Sub


'below Calculating difference b/t Checkin & Checkout, displaying in "TOTALHRS" textbox

Sub GetTime()       
    Dim Time1, Time2, TotalTime  As Date
    Time1 = CHKIN.Text
    Time2 = CHKOUT.Text
    TotalTime = DateDiff("s", Time1, Time2)
    TotalTime = Totalhour / 86400
    TOTALHRS.Text = Format(Totalhour, "hh:mm")
End Sub


'Using below code to convert checkin and checkout input in hh:mm format.

Private Sub CHKIN_AfterUpdate()
    Dim tDate As Date
    Dim tString As String
    With CHKIN
        'Check if user put in a colon or not
        If InStr(1, .Value, ":", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            'If not, make string 4 digits and insert colon
            tString = Format(.Value, "0000")
            tDate = TimeSerial(Left(tString, 2), Right(tString, 2), 0)

            CHKIN.Value = Format(tDate, "HH:MM")
        Else
            'Otherwise, take value as given
            .Value = Format(.Value, "hh:mm")
        End If
    End With
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Desired result wanted: `checkout` - `checkin` = `hh:mm`
Example: `23:20` - `9:35` = `13:45`

Comment: Tell us what have you learned about syntax of DateDiff.

Comment: [Datediff function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function) takes dates as parameters, you need to format those strings into dates before attempting datediff. Also Totalhour is not being used appropriately either.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but good code hygiene helps, `Call` is deprecated. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of modules - always. This will identify some errors in your current code that you can then fix. Properly indent your code, this makes it easier to read and, hence, understand and maintain.

Comment: `TotalTime = Totalhour / 86400` will throw an error as `Totalhour` is not initialised, not defined and empty.  It should probably be `TotalTimeTotalhour = TotalTime / 86400` Tidy up your code and use proper validation.  There are lots of issues at the moment.

Comment: Dear All ,sorry to say  "Totalhour" is a typo mistake , it is actually "TotalTime" , Could some show me an example to correct this ?

Comment: Guys , Kindly help me with code part , AJD : i have tried Option Explicit but still getting the same error . Dear  – Gareth plz help

Comment: The main problem probably is that `Dim Time1, Time2, TotalTime  As Date` only declares `TotalTime As Date` but the other 2 as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default: `Dim Time1 As Date, Time2 As Date, TotalTime As Date`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have already tried that but it didnt help me .

Comment: @JAV In which line do you get the mismatch error?